# Go, how to import struct and fields of other packages?

Tags: go, struct, package

i have the next problem, if I try to export a struct of other package, call a method of get Dates, and get the field with ( struct.field), it doesn´t work

```
//main/other
package other

type Birthday struct{
     Day string
}

func (b *Birthday) SetDay(){
     b.Day = "10"
}

//main
package main

import ("main/other")

func main(){
    f := other.Birthday{}
    f.SetDay()
    fmt.Println(f.Day) // ""   no return nothing
}
```

but when i use the func main in the same file of the struct, this ones works.

Comment: Can you show your `go.mod` file?

Comment: Does your actual code compile? Are there any errors? And in your actual code are you using `func (b *Birthday) SetDay()` or could it be that, perhaps, you have `func (b Birthday) SetDay()`?

Comment: Read and _follow_ (!!) https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started. No shortcuts, no but-I-know-better, no but-I-want, no but-random-YT-tutorial-said, no but-I-don't-need. Just follow it word for word.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your program [on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hmwMUGB33Xm):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "play.ground/foo"
)

func main() {
    f := foo.Birthday{}
    f.SetDay()
    fmt.Println(f.Day)
}
-- go.mod --
module play.ground
-- foo/foo.go --
package foo

type Birthday struct {
    Day string
}

func (b *Birthday) SetDay() {
    b.Day = "10"
}
```

It does work just fine.
Make sure to `go mod init yourProject` first; as detailed in "[Tutorial: Create a Go module](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module)".